# How is my position named?

Tags: job

My advisor is responsible for assigning teachers to conducting excercises to lectures. Since there is a lot of students (and groups) sometimes last year students help by taking excercises in some groups. For the past 5 months I've been employed by the university and I've worked a couple of hours a week taking classes, without a formal position at the university (and for sure won't have until I finish my masters).

Right now I am writing a CV and I would like to include the last 5 months in my work experience but I don't know how to name my position - is "Math teacher @ university" a good one?

Comment: Have you considered reading your contract for these details?

Comment: Yes, but the contract is regarding conducting  X classess, there is no formal position named, and "math teacher" sounds a bit high-schoolish.

Comment: I'd ask your advisor on this. If you are getting paid then I'm surprised they don't have a title listed somewhere for you, even if it is an internal title.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're doing. Are you leading a separate tutorial/exercise session that runs concurrently with lectures? If so, I would say you're a teaching assistant or in the British system a Tutor running a tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I lead separate excercise sessions on which I show how to apply what they learned on lectures in practice. THanks for the response i think teaching assistant is suitable here.

Answer (score 5):

Having worked at a university in HR, you are classified as an employee and you definitely have a "job title". Since you're a graduate student, you could be classified as a "Teaching Assistant" or "Graduate Assistant". I would recommend reaching out to your HR department and simply asking them what you your title is in the system.